# Issue while publishing existing git repo to github-pages using npm run deploy

Tags: reactjs, git, github, github-pages

I'm trying to publish a website on GitHub-pages using `gh-pages` module.

Here is my **package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "rahmanstatic_website",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "https://rahmanharoon.github.io/Rahman-Protfolio",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.2.2",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-icons": "^4.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-hash-link": "^2.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "react-scroll": "^1.8.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

I have been already pushed the code to GitHub branch. So I called **npm run build** When It started deploying I got an error and I searched online and I didn't get a proper result. Here is the *error*

[image]

I checked my environment variables its path is C:\Windows\System32 (I think there is no issue with environment variables)

Here is the **.gitignore** :

```
# See https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/ for more about ignoring files.

# dependencies
/node_modules
/.pnp
.pnp.js

# testing
/coverage

# production
/build

# misc
.DS_Store
.env.local
.env.development.local
.env.test.local
.env.production.local

npm-debug.log*
yarn-debug.log*
yarn-error.log*
```

Any suggestion will be helpful

Comment: Hello,
Can you confirm that if you run `git remote -v` you get your repo URL ?
And on Github, you configured Github pages to track your master branch ?

Comment: Yeah I have config github pages but i run `git remote -v` its showing `git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,`

Comment: So even if you checked it, I think there is a problem with env vars.
Instead of running the command in windows prompt, try to run it with **Git bash**

Comment: Here is the link am getting after published using git bash https://rahmanharoon.github.io/Rahman-Protfolio/

Comment: I can get the git repo URl when run `git remote -v` using git bash @jean-smaug

Answer (score 0):

In the settings of your repo you need to select the correct path ?

And make sure that your repo contains your build ?

Maybe you need to remove the build folder from `.gitignore`

[image]

Comment: Yeah my path is correct.. I added gitignore file content on question please check that

Comment: Remove the `/build` from your .gitignore.

Run `npm run build` or `yarn build` and commit the build folder ;)
I assume it's a Create React App

Comment: https://rahmanharoon.github.io/Rahman-Protfolio/ this is the link after publishing. The  readme.md content is showing on that